# Updating/Saving to a SQL Database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, save

I can't find how to do this on google anywhere. How do you save to a SQL DB using just C# code? Is it possible? The save method that comes default when you create a DB using the wizard dosen't actually save the DB:

```
this.Validate();
this.studentsBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.studentsTableAdapter.Update(this.studentsDataSet.FirstClass);
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "Save" the DB?

Comment: Actually update the file on the server not just the table adapter.

Comment: Are you able to retrieve data successfully from SqlServer?

Comment: Yep, it loads and when I click the save button it dosen't throw any exceptions or anything. I'm using SQL Server Express Edition and C# 2008 Express Edition. Does either of these matter? It's also stored on the localhost, as I don't have a server lying around :P

Comment: see additional question below

Comment: and come on, what kind of computer geek doesn't have an extra computer or two kicking around ;-)

Comment: Oh I forgot I put the server next to my rack mount server that also has RAID with SCSI drives!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though you are doing it correctly.

You should check your table adapter and verify that there is an update statement assigned. If you're using sprocs and only have the select sproc assigned then it'll be read only (and won't prompt you for the update/insert/delete sprocs).

Comment: I'm a newbie when it comes to SQL programming, what are sprocs?

Comment: SQL "stored procedures", but since you ask I presume that this is not reason.

Comment: If you do select your tableadapter and then expand the UpdateCommand property, there is a CommandText property, does that have a value?

Comment: I can't seem to find the UpdateCommand property in my tableadapter?

Comment: you've got your dataset open in design view?

Comment: Here is what was in that feild: UPDATE [dbo].[People] SET [ID] = @ID, [Name] = @Name WHERE (([ID] = @Original_ID));
SELECT ID, Name FROM People WHERE (ID = @ID)

Comment: This is weird isn't it? Could there be something wrong with the way my SQL server is configured.

Comment: and do you know how to use it? (don't mean to be insulting)

Comment: I don't have SQL Server Management studio, I only have the express edition.

Comment: I don't think it would be configured wrong, updates are pretty standard.

Comment: can you run "raw" sql commands from it? if so try "SELECT ID, Name FROM People" (if there aren't too many rows in it), I'm wondering if it's actually updating and your application is perhaps caching the data.

Comment: I guess your right, but hey were talking about microsoft here ;-)

Comment: I'm gonna sound like a total newb but my problem is this: I'll post it as an answer so you can see the pic.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string can be a few things depending on how you are configured to log into SQL.

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

or

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

The latter is if you are using Windows Authentication; i.e. using the same user account you log into windows with.

DataSource is usually your machine's name or you can use (local) to get you over the hump should it be on the same machine you are working on.